# Sales Order list on customer screen copyPast error

Tags: acumatica

Good day

I created a customer grid on my customer screen showing the sales order for that customer. After adding the grid the copy past functionality of the customer screen is giving me an error.

```
"Error: Inserting  'Carrier Plugin Customer' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors. Error: 'Customer' cannot be empty."
```

After adding the following to the new grid the error started:

```
    public PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.customerID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>>> SOList;
```

Is there code or configuration I can add/change so that the copy past ignores this new grid as it should only display the data.
As far as I can see the copy past is trying to add these sales orders again

edit:
the other error I get when clicking the past action is:

```
"The system failed to commit the SOList row."
```

edit 2:
Link to sample code:

https://aboutitgroup-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/jaco_aboutitgroup_co_za/EVJfMcBUjvxDktSaBD1DUNYBqiQEGABTqsreVdymDFjTDw?e=6jSFj2

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is trying to copy the orders now that they are a part of the screen.

For any inquiry based data view added make sure you exclude the view from the copy paste process by adding the `PXCopyPasteHiddenViewAttribute` to your view.

**Ex:**

```
[PXCopyPasteHiddenView]
public PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.customerID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>>> SOList;
```

If needed you can limit the copy and paste to select fields you can use `PXCopyPasteHiddenFieldsAttribute`. Below is an example copied from OpportunityMaint. This attribute can also be applied to the DAC directly to exclude fields used on any graph.

**Ex:**

```
[PXCopyPasteHiddenFields(typeof(CROpportunity.details), typeof(CROpportunity.stageID), typeof(CROpportunity.resolution))]
        public PXSelect<CROpportunity,
            Where<CROpportunity.opportunityID, Equal<Current<CROpportunity.opportunityID>>>>
            OpportunityCurrent;
```

Comment: Hi Brendan this doesn't seem to help with the issue. If you have time I made a customization project with just this tab view in the customer tab. it is now in the original post